# How to have Refresh2 method with .net WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have vb6 project that uses Refresh2 method of WebBrowser. 
How I can access this method in .net project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebBrowser control in WinForms has two Refresh methods:

```
public void Refresh();
public void Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption opt);
```

The second one in fact calls `Refresh2()` on the underlying COM component. Just pass in the enum value that you want, depending on the refresh options that you want.

Comment: I cannot find what is default value for WebBrowser.Refresh2 method

Comment: @volody I don't think it has a default value - you have to pass in the value that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend re-writing WebBrowserRefreshOption opt to any ieRefreshConstants enum such as
Refresh2(ieRefreshConstants.REFRESH_COMPLETELY);

where

```
enum ieRefreshConstants {
       REFRESH_NORMAL = 0,
       REFRESH_IFEXPIRED = 1,
       REFRESH_COMPLETELY = 3
};
```

According to MSDN
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768363(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)